# StreamingFileSink forBulkFormat vs forRowFormat with avro encoder

Tags: apache-flink

I have the Flink of 4 version and want to update it to 11. I try to use `StreamingFileSink` instead of the deprecated `BucketingSink`. My code is looks like:

```
val sink = StreamingFileSink
  .forBulkFormat(new Path(s"${conf.output}/$path") , AvroWriters.forReflectRecord[T](clazz) )
  .withBucketCheckInterval(toMillis(config.inactiveBucketThreshold))
  .withBucketAssigner(bucketAssigner)
  .build()
```

But I have a problem with writing to fs in tests.

Which advantages are there to use `StreamingFileSink.forBulkFormat` instead of  `StreamingFileSink.forRowFormat` with avro encoder?

Could you help to write an example of usage second way?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Please, refer to the [following "Row format or bulk format" thread](http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Row-format-or-bulk-format-td25253.html) for a bit of details.</strike>

In short, at least up to version `1.11`, flink provides only `BulkWriter` factory for avro format - `AvroWriterFactory`, which you can use out of the box.

To use the row format - `StreamingFileSink.forRowFormat` - you need to provide your own implementation of `org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.Encoder` interface which will be able to encode and to append data to part files record by record.

As an example, you can have a look at `org.apache.flink.formats.json.JsonFileSystemFormatFactory.JsonRowDataEncoder` .

Comment: that link is dead